# How to display a note if a row does not exist? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display all phone numbers of my `customer(Customertable)`.

But if there is no phone number because the customer hasn't left one, I want to display a note saying "No phone number".

I've tried it with the command

```
Select phonenumber 
From Customers
if phonenumber is NUll RAISEERROR 'No phonenumber'  -error
```

But I get an error:

> "Phonenumber" is not a valid columnname

and i guess `RAISEERROR` is also not the proper way to display a note (?!)

Please help

Sorry for poor English.

Comment: Perhaps the column name is different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use `coalesce` to return the first non-null value?

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(phonenumber, 'no phone number')
FROM customers
```

Answer (score 2):

`RAISEEROR` seems rather brutal.

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(phonenumber), 'No phonenumber')
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId;
```

The purpose of `MAX()` is to return a single row for a given customer.

However, this sort of logic should be at the application layer, and probably not embedded in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I do not know what do you mean by there is no phonenumber, it can be null or an empty char so this is my gues:

```
Select case when phonenumber is null or phonenumber ="" then
'No phonenumber' 
else phonenumber end
 FROM Customers
```

Comment: Make this `phonenumber = ''`. Double quotes are for aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNULL` function

> ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )

Please find description on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

I hope this will help you

```
SELECT
   ISNULL(phonenumber, 'no phone number')
FROM customers
```